# Controlling one page controls on other page

Tags: c#, asp.net, modalpopupextender

I have been working on a project and i got stucked on in a problem as i have a popup on a page student.aspx and the popup get visible onpageload and i have another page as email.aspx and also email page do contain the  button,what i want is when i click on a button the popup should get invisible. 
i got a solution as

```
if (Page.PreviousPage != null){

TextBox SourceTextBox = 

    (TextBox)Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("TextBox1");

if (SourceTextBox != null)

{

    Label1.Text = SourceTextBox.Text;

}}
```

how to implement it with modalpopupextender

Comment: you just want to `hide` or `show` the `modalpopupextender` on button click.

Comment: from `email.aspx` you want to control or `hide` your `modalpopupextender` that is placed on `student.aspx` page,right

Comment: after `hide` the `modelpopupextender` you want to focus on `email.aspx` page or on `student.aspx` page..means when your `modelpopextender` will `hide` from `email` page then you want to open which page means control which page..

Comment: just set the `page name` in `session variable` when you will click on button placed on email page and redirect it to `student` page and check first if `session` field name is same as you mentioned then use `Modalpopupextender.Hide();` method.